# API block message errors

Tags: objective-c, api, objective-c-blocks

trying to send the following message

```
- (NSArray *)callSwaggerwithStart:(NSNumber *)start andCount:(NSNumber *)count
{
    [api messageWithCompletionBlock:start count:count filter:@"image" completionHandler:^(CustomResponse *output, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            return [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[output toDictionary] valueForKey:@"items"]];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"ERROR IN CallApi, %@", &error);
        }
    }];
    return nil;
}
```

I get the following errors:

`Incompatible block pointer types`

`Control may reach end of non-void block`

The block is from an Api class, and I would like to create a method since it is used multiple times in one controller. What is keeping the code from being able to return the nested NSArray value?

Comment: Why does the `callSwaggerwithStart...` method have a return value? It's pointless when dealing with a asynchronous block that won't return data until long after the method returns. You need to rethink how this works.

Comment: I had added the return value, will be removing it then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API  completion block is executed asynchronously, so you cannot synchronously return anything it computes to the caller of `callSwaggerWithStart...`. The completionHandler is likely to be executed much later than the method returns.

A valid approach would be to also make `callSwaggerWithStart...` asynchronous, as follows:

```
- (void)callSwaggerwithStart:(NSNumber *)start andCount:(NSNumber *)count completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *result, NSError *error))completionHandler
{
    [api messageWithCompletionBlock:start count:count filter:@"image" completionHandler:^(CustomResponse *output, NSError *error) {
        if (completionHandler) {
            if (!error) {
                completionHandler([output toDictionary][@"items"]], error);
            } else {
                completionHandler(nil, error);
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: +1 Awesome @GP, and nice to see this pattern to handle blocks for blocks

Answer (score 1):

The `-messageWithCompletionBlock:etc:` method appears to be asynchronous, which means that, as it’s currently written, the block will get called after `-callSwaggerEtc:` returns. The “return” inside the block returns from the block, not from the method itself You have two options—change `-callSwaggerEtc:` to take a completion handler of its own, or use a [semaphore](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW24) to make it synchronous and wait to return until the block gets called.

Comment: Ooph, what a mistake was that return

Answer (score 0):

`start` is an `NSNumber`, not a block. Or `messageWithCompletionBlock:` is really badly named...

`completionHandler` does not expect a return. It's also a block, so returning from there just exits the block, not the containing method.

Your method expects to return an array, you expect to be able to do that from within a block - you are mistaken. You need to change your design so the method doesn't return an array (maybe it calls a block that it is passed as a parameter) or it gets the array in a different way.

Comment: I strongly suspect it's badly named.